# Problem deploying Spring application on WebLogic

Tags: spring, weblogic, pitchfork

We're trying to to run an application using Spring on Weblogic 10.3.3. This, apparently, should be straightforward, and just involves ensuring various additional jars (notably pitchfork) are in the library directory for weblogic, and getting the config right.
Unfortunately, when we try to deploy, we keep experiencing the error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.jee.spi.PitchforkUtilsImpl cannot be cast to com.oracle.pitchfork.interfaces.PitchforkUtils

Which seems reasonable, as PitchforkUtilsImpl doesn't implement com.oracle.pitchfork.interfaces.PitchforkUtils - it implements some springframework interface of that name.

Can anyone offer some advice on what we're doing wrong, please?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650397/classcastexception-with-weblogic-10-3-3-pitchfork